# How can I make orderBy refresh on every change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I have a function that checks if a value is true or false and a function that changes value.

```
checkValue(item){  
    if item.exists{  
        return 1;  
    }  
    else {  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

and in my html I have a `ng-repeat` that orders by this function:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: checkValue"></span>
<a ng-click="changeItemExists(selectedItem)">
```

now when `item.exists` change the `orderBy` does not work again and order the spans again.

How can I make the orderBy to watch for any changes in the `item.exsist`?

Comment: add `$scope.checkValueitem = selectedItem;` in your `changeItemExists()` function.

and change `checkValue(item)` to `checkValue(){var item = $scope.checkValueItem; }`

Comment: Please don't put non related tag to your question, this question have nothing to do with Angular. It's AngularJS only.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `checkValue` function.
Just do:

```
<span ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'exists'"></span>
```

Then the `orderBy` will refresh the order automatic on any changes of the 'exists' property.